# Как правильно выдавать исключения?

Tags: c++, c, ооп, исключения

Понял что не знаю как правильно выдавать исключения. К примеру если в файл не получилось открыть, я закрывал приложение аварийно, однако как делают правильно?

Для этого есть исключение, как именно использоваться? к примеру

```
void doing_with_file(const char* name){
    if (fopen_s(...) != 0 || fp == NULL){
        qDebug()<<"File not found";
        throw 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    try {
        doing_with_file("file.txt");
    catch (int a) {
        if(a==1)
          //сделать что-то
    }

}
```

Comment: Исключения лучше не выдавать. Хорошая программа - та которая не выдаёт исключений. Очень спорный момент, разные программы по разному выводят исключения. Некоторые предлагают "отчёт" на мейл прислать или что-то такое. Единого правила на исключения думаю нет и не будет.

Comment: А имеется ввиду выдавать сам себе, или пользователю? Пользователю чайнику, или пользователю умеющему работать с ПК? Или администатору?

Comment: 1. Вывод сообщения - Можно писать например MessageBox, можно писать в файл, можно в лог-журнал винды. 2. Можно самому составлять сообщение, можно попросить систему дать по коду ошибки текст ошибки, можно дополнять текст ошибки разными деталями, можно просто извесный код ошибки писать который легко гуглится, например HRESULT код или LastError код - очень много неизвесных - поэтому невозможно однозначно ответить.

Comment: пользователю чайнику, поэтому наверное messageBox буду использовать, спасибо

Comment: Ошибок с файлом может быть много. Файл не найден, отказано в доступе, защищен от записи (CD-карта в ноуте например), ошибка ввода-вывода, файл занят другой программой... и ещё несколько вариантов, поэтому в catch нужно брать код ошибки, и по коду ошибки смотреть, потому что напишите файл не найден - а там другая ситуация...